# Symfony2: Persist a 2-way relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

A Household entity has a 1:n relationship with a Member entity.  These entities are straightforward to persist when creating a new Household.  What eludes me is how best to designate one and only one of the Member collection as Head of Household.  The model shows the Household entity with the id of the Member that is head and the Member entities have the id of the Household.  So when a Household entity and constituent Member entities are created the id of the head is not known. I'm looking for suggestions on how to establish this Head of Household relationship.

Per request, the code.  Solution code added within.  Credit should go to commenter nifr!!:

#### Household entity snippet (hohId is id of head of household, clients are members):

```
    /**
     * Household
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="household")
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Household
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="hoh_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
         */
        private $hohId;
    ...
        /**
         * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         *
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Client", mappedBy="household")
         * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
         */
        private $clients;
    ...
//added for solution:
    /**
     * @var object Member as head of household
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Member")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hoh_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *      */
    private $head;

    public function setHead($member) {
        $this->head = $member;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHead() {
        return $this->head;
    }

    }
```

#### Client (really, member) entity snippet:

```
/**
 * Client
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="client", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idx_client_household_idx", columns={"household_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="idx_client_ethnicity_idx", columns={"ethnicity_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
...
    /**
     * @var \Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Household
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Household", inversedBy="clients", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="household_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $household;
...
}
```

#### HouseholdType form class snippet:

```
        ->add('isHead','choice', array(
            'expanded' => true,
            'mapped' => false,
        )
```

#### Prototype form snippet:

```
<tr id="member-form">
<td><input class="smallform" type="radio" name="household[isHead]" value="__name__"></td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.fname, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.sname, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.dob, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.sex, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.ethnicity, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
```

#### HouseholdController snippet:

```
    public function createAction(Request $request) {
        $household = new Household();

        $form = $this->createForm(new HouseholdType(), $household);
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $members = $household->getMembers();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            //get household head index
            $h = $request->request->get('household');
            $hohIdx = $h['isHead'];
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($members as $member) {
                if ($i == $hohIdx) {
                    $household->setHead($member);
                }
                $i++;
                $member->setHousehold($household);
            }
            $em->persist($household);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('household_show', array('id' => $household->getId())));
        }
//...
}
```

Comment: could you add some code and hint us to your exact problem ... maybe rephrase the question a bit more general? what are you expecting? entities, controller code?

Comment: @nifr: Code added above.  Hope it helps!

Comment: hm shouldn't your head of household be an additional one-to-one relation with client instead of just the id? Being able to call `$household->getHead()` will simplify things

Comment: @nifr: I'm considering creating the one-to-one.  I just can't quite get my head around where it helps solve the problem of `$household->setHead($clientId)` when I don't have an id!

Comment: ...  you could add a non-mapped by doctrine property to your client entity ... lets call it 'isHead' ... then you add your entities to the collection in the form and add a checkbox for is_head to the ClientFormType, ensure via JavaScript that there is only one of them clicked , further validate that on submission there is only one entity present with is_head set to true ... afterwards loop over the collection somewhat like this `foreach ($household->getClients() as $client) { if ($client->isHead()) { $household->setHead($client); break; } }` ... got the idea?

Comment: @nifr: Most excellent!  I'll cobble together a test to see how it goes.  Will report back.

Comment: @nifr: This works!!! (Post as answer  & I'll accept.)  Instead of a checkbox I added a radio button (only one response) in the prototype.  This is a little tricky - use the same variable name structure as appears in the DOM of the added form, with its value being incremented in the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamentals of the solution are as follows. Credit should go to commenter nifr!.

#### Household entity snippet (hohId is id of head of household, clients are members):

```
    /**
     * Household
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="household")
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Household
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="hoh_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
         */
        private $hohId;
    ...
        /**
         * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         *
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Client", mappedBy="household")
         * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
         */
        private $clients;
    ...
//added for solution:
    /**
     * @var object Member as head of household
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Member")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hoh_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *      */
    private $head;

    public function setHead($member) {
        $this->head = $member;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHead() {
        return $this->head;
    }

    }
```

#### Client (really, member) entity snippet:

```
/**
 * Client
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="client", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idx_client_household_idx", columns={"household_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="idx_client_ethnicity_idx", columns={"ethnicity_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
...
    /**
     * @var \Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Household
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Household", inversedBy="clients", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="household_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $household;
...
}
```

#### HouseholdType form class snippet:

```
        ->add('isHead','choice', array(
            'expanded' => true,
            'mapped' => false,
        )
```

#### Prototype form snippet:

```
<tr id="member-form">
<td><input class="smallform" type="radio" name="household[isHead]" value="__name__"></td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.fname, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.sname, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.dob, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.sex, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.ethnicity, {'attr': {'class':'smallform'}}) }}</td>
```

#### HouseholdController snippet:

```
    public function createAction(Request $request) {
        $household = new Household();

        $form = $this->createForm(new HouseholdType(), $household);
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $members = $household->getMembers();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            //get household head index
            $h = $request->request->get('household');
            $hohIdx = $h['isHead'];
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($members as $member) {
                if ($i == $hohIdx) {
                    $household->setHead($member);
                }
                $i++;
                $member->setHousehold($household);
            }
            $em->persist($household);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('household_show', array('id' => $household->getId())));
        }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**remove the collecton from the entety and try something like this**

```
/**
     * Household
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="household")
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Household
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="hoh_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
         */
        private $hohId;
    ...
     /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "Household",mappedBy="household", cascade={"remove","persist","merge"})
     */
        private $clients;
    ...
    }
```

**and this**

```
/**
 * Client
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="client", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idx_client_household_idx", columns={"household_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="idx_client_ethnicity_idx", columns={"ethnicity_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
...
    /**
     * @var \Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Household
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Household", inversedBy="clients", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="household_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $household;
...
}
```